# From List into ArcPy Feature Class with InsertCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, nmea, typeerror

I am parsing an NMEA file to be able to import it into an ArcGIS with arcpy. I finalised the parsing part and also created a list with the appropriate form. But if I'm trying to insert the List into the Attribute Table via an InsertCursor, I continously get the following error:

```
line 127, in <module>
cursor.insertRow(a) TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

I already figured out that there are quotation marks in the list that causes the problem, but I really don't know how to create a workaround here. I already tried to make an array, but unfortunately I to  stick to float values for the Longitude and Latitude.

This is how my code looks like:

```
import arcpy
#arcpy.env.workspace = env_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
#nmea = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

data = open('C:/temp/NMEA.txt', 'r')
input = data.read()
input2=input.split('\n')

GGA = list();

for lines in input2:
    if '$GPGGA' in lines:
        GGA.append(lines)

GGA2 = ''.join(GGA)
GGA3 = GGA2.split(",")

UTC = list();
Latitude = list();
Comp1 = list();
Longitude = list();
Comp2 = list();
GPSQual = list();
SatVis = list();
HDOP = list();
AntAlt = list();
AntHeight = list();
GeoidalSep1 = list();
SeaLevel = list();
GeoidalSep2 = list();
Age = list();
DifRef = list();
Check = list();

for item in GGA3:
    GGA3.pop(0)
    UTC.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    Latitude.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    Comp1.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    Longitude.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    Comp2.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    GPSQual.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    SatVis.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    HDOP.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    AntAlt.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    AntHeight.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    GeoidalSep1.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    SeaLevel.append(GGA3.pop(0))
    DifRef.append(GGA3.pop(0))

# NMEA Coordinate Format
#(d)ddmm.mmmm
#(d)dd + (mm.mmmm/60) (* -1 for W and S)

# Calculation Longitude
minLong = list();
degLong = list();
for x in Longitude:
    minLong.append((x[-10:]))
    degLong.append((x[0:3]))

minLongInt = map(float,minLong)
degLongInt = map(int,degLong)

minLongCalc = list();
for x in minLongInt:
    minLongCalc.append(x/60)

LongCalc = [x +y for x,y in zip(degLongInt, minLongCalc)]

# Calculation Latitude
minLat = list();
degLat = list();
for x in Latitude:
    minLat.append((x[-10:]))
    degLat.append((x[0:2]))

minLatInt = map(float,minLat)
degLatInt = map(float,degLat)

minLatCalc = list();
for x in minLatInt:
    minLatCalc.append(x/60)

LatCalc = [x +y for x,y in zip(degLatInt, minLatCalc)]

GPSQaulInt = map(float,GPSQual)
SatVisInt = map(float,SatVis)
HDOPInt = map(float,HDOP)
AntAltInt = map(float,AntAlt)


a = list();
for i in range(len(LatCalc)):
    a.append("('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}',({},{}),)".format(LatCalc[i],LongCalc[i],GPSQual[i],SatVis[i],HDOP[i],AntAlt[i],LatCalc[i],LongCalc[i]))


#Create NMEA Shape

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("C:/tmp/","ParsedNMEA.shp","POINT","","DISABLED","DISABLED",4326,"","","","")
NMEAFile = "C:/tmp/ParsedNMEA.shp"
arcpy.AddField_management(NMEAFile,"X","DOUBLE",23,15,"","","NON_NULLABLE","REQUIRED")
arcpy.AddField_management(NMEAFile,"Y","DOUBLE", 23, 15, "", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")
arcpy.AddField_management(NMEAFile,"GPSQuality","SHORT", 15, "", 10, "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED")
arcpy.AddField_management(NMEAFile,"SatVis","TEXT", 15, "", 10, "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED")
arcpy.AddField_management(NMEAFile,"HDOP","FLOAT", 5, 15, "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED")
arcpy.AddField_management(NMEAFile,"AntHeight","DOUBLE", 20, 15, "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED")

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(NMEAFile,("X","Y","GPSQuality","SatVis","HDOP","AntHeight","SHAPE@XY"))
for i in range(len(a)):
    cursor.insertRow(a)
```

My approach is based on the example in [ESRIs arcpy documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm):

```
import arcpy

# A list of values that will be used to construct new rows
row_values = [('Anderson', (1409934.4442000017, 1076766.8192000017)),
              ('Andrews', (752000.2489000037, 1128929.8114))]

# Open an InsertCursor
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('C:/data/texas.gdb/counties',
                               ['NAME', 'SHAPE@XY'])

# Insert new rows that include the county name and a x,y coordinate
#  pair that represents the county center
for row in row_values:
    cursor.insertRow(row)
```

I am working with ArcGIS 10.4 and PythonWin (Python 2.7).

Output of my list looks like this:

```
["('47.78892519','13.0611603033','1','06','1.0','435.838',(47.78892519,13.0611603033),)", "('47.7889243533','13.061157485','1','06','1.0','436.367',(47.7889243533,13.061157485),)"]
```

Can anyone help me out with an workaround?

Comment: Your `row _ values` isn't formatted as an array of arrays or list of arrays, it's an array of lists,.

Comment: Exactly this is the interesting point here. But a) how can i create arrays of arrays with float values and b) don't I continuously end up with lists when I doing the formation of the data with .format? I already searched for a another way to create formatted lists but I didn't come up with a answer....

Comment: If you structure your strings as JSON, you just need to convert the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be trying to do to much of the thinking for python - let it take care of the data types.
I haven't created a test case for this, so I may have missed something...

I think you can simply initialize `a` as an empty list and then append each row as a tuple - as in the docs you reference. Only 'SatVis' should be different since it's datatype is a string.

Basically replace this:

```
a = list();
for i in range(len(LatCalc)):
    a.append("('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}',({},{}),)".format(LatCalc[i],LongCalc[i],GPSQual[i],SatVis[i],HDOP[i],AntAlt[i],LatCalc[i],LongCalc[i]))
```

with this:

```
a = []
for i in range(len(LatCalc)):
    a.append((LatCalc[i],LongCalc[i],GPSQual[i],"'{}'".format(SatVis[i]),HDOP[i],AntAlt[i],(LatCalc[i],LongCalc[i])))
```

Your output should be a list of tuples not a list of strings which *look* like tuples!

Comment: Thank's so much! This was the appropriate way to go and it worked!!